# Facebook Graph API PHP SDK -> Grabbing data from public page without login

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I apologize in advance if this question is horrible.

My goal is to have my website grab data (events) from one specific facebook page that I own, and then display that data on the appropriate website.

I'm new to the facebook graph API. I downloaded and set up the PHP SDK to use on my website.

I created the initial $fb object as it stated to do within the SDK "Getting Started" page.

However, the next step in the system is creating a way for users to "login" and with this it generates the required access token.

On my site, I have absolutely no reason to have a user login.

I am so lost, that I am not even sure what to ask.

I guess, what do I have to do so that I can get an authorization token that will grab public data, without having the visitors to the website authorize an app or login.

I have searched a lot over the last few hours, but the only thing i can find is the document on how to have users log in to get the access token.

Any answer or documentation linked would be so greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: For public page content, you can simply use your app access token.

Comment: Is that the app Id, app secret, or something located elsewhere?

Comment: App id and secret concatenated with a pipe symbol always works as app access token. (There‘s also an endpoint to request one dynamically [see docs], but that’s hardly ever needed.)